# Hover text pushing text down and overwriting list

Tags: css, hover

I am using CSS to create a hover over text paragraph for a list of items. When I hover over the first one, the remainder are pushed down the screen, overwriting each other. I am a CSS/HTML novice so my apologies if I am asking a foolish question.[

```css
#DivForHoverItem {
 height: 20px;
 width: auto;
}

#HiddenText {
 display: none;
}

#DivForHoverItem:hover #HiddenText {
 display: block;
 background-color: #D3D3D5;
 opacity: 1.0
 top: -23px;
 bottom: auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 15px;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 background-attachment:local;
}
```

```html
<div id="DivForHoverItem"><p>Topic 1: Questions, puzzlement and what is okay</p>
<div id="HiddenText"><p>We begin to engage students in the ways of thinking and the pedagogical (or teaching) approach that underlie the Primary Ethics curriculum, as well as to build understanding about the behaviour expected in ethics classes.</p></div></div>

<div id="DivForHoverItem"><p>Topic 2: Secrets and a big, important question</p>
<div id="HiddenText"><p>We aim to foster students' developing capacity to make logical inferences and encourage and support students to think for themselves about the ethical question of whether or not it is okay to tell a friend's secret.</p></div></div>

<div id="DivForHoverItem"><p>Topic 3: Doing harm without meaning to</p>
<div id="HiddenText"><p>We encourage students to think for themselves about the difference between 'meaning' or intending to cause harm and causing harm 'accidentally' or without wanting to.</p></div></div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2yrY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you want to do like this? :

```css
#DivForHoverItem {     
      float:left;
      clear:both;
}

#HiddenText {
        float:left;
 display: none;
}

#DivForHoverItem:hover #HiddenText {
 display: block;
 background-color: #D3D3D5;
 opacity: 1.0;
 position:relative;
        padding-left:15px;
 float:left;
 background-attachment:local;
}
```

```html
<div id="DivForHoverItem"><p>Topic 1: Questions, puzzlement and what is okay</p>
<div id="HiddenText"><p>We begin to engage students in the ways of thinking and the pedagogical (or teaching) approach that underlie the Primary Ethics curriculum, as well as to build understanding about the behaviour expected in ethics classes.</p></div></div>

<div id="DivForHoverItem"><p>Topic 2: Secrets and a big, important question</p>
<div id="HiddenText"><p>We aim to foster students' developing capacity to make logical inferences and encourage and support students to think for themselves about the ethical question of whether or not it is okay to tell a friend's secret.</p></div></div>

<div id="DivForHoverItem"><p>Topic 3: Doing harm without meaning to</p>
<div id="HiddenText"><p>We encourage students to think for themselves about the difference between 'meaning' or intending to cause harm and causing harm 'accidentally' or without wanting to.</p></div></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If a solution is helpful and working for you, please click on "tick" icon to approve this aswer and you can also use up votes in stackoverflow. :)